# Why my functions does not update when I add another data in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem when it comes to adding another set of data in the database when I called the `getCatItem()` function. The function only allowed one set of data to be displayed in my website and the other set of data can't be added. I have tried using another method but it won't work either.

**This is my initial code :**

```
function getCats(){

    global $con; 

    $get_cats = "select * from category";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

    while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $cat_id = $row_cats['category_id']; 
        $cat_title = $row_cats['category'];
        echo "<ul><a href='Equipment.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></ul>";
    }

}
```

**If I don't involved 'cat', the code will update every time I add data to the database.**

```
function getItem(){

    if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){

        global $con; 

        $get_pro = "select * from item order by RAND() LIMIT 0,30";
        $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro); 

        while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
            $pro_id = $row_pro['itemID'];
            $pro_cat = $row_pro['cat_id'];
            $pro_title = $row_pro['item_name'];
            $pro_amount = $row_pro['item_amount'];
            $pro_detail = $row_pro['item_detail'];
            $pro_image = $row_pro['item_image'];

            echo "

        <figure>
        <img src='administrator/product_images/$pro_image' width ='150px' height ='300px'>
        <figcaption style ='text-align : center;'>Item Name : $pro_title</figcaption>
        <figcaption style ='text-align : center;'>Description : $pro_detail</figcaption>
        <figcaption style ='text-align : center;'>Quantity : $pro_amount</figcaption>
        <a class='button' href='Booking.php'>Book Now</a>
        </figure>

        ";

        }
    }
}
```

**Then, I add category in the code, the item only showed once, then it can not be added anymore.**

```
function getCatItem(){

    if(isset($_GET['cat'])){

        $cat_id = $_GET['cat'];

        global $con; 

        $get_cat_pro = "select * from item where cat_id='$cat_id'";
        $run_cat_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_cat_pro); 
        $count_cats = mysqli_num_rows($run_cat_pro);

        if($count_cats==0){
            echo "<h2 style='padding:20px;'>No products where found in this category!</h2>";
        }

        while($row_cat_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat_pro)){

            $pro_id = $row_cat_pro['item_id'];
            $pro_cat = $row_cat_pro['cat_id'];
            $pro_title = $row_cat_pro['item_name'];
            $pro_amount = $row_cat_pro['item_amount'];
            $pro_detail = $row_cat_pro['item_detail'];
            $pro_image = $row_cat_pro['item_image'];

            echo "
            <div id='columns' class='columns_4'>
             <figure>
        <img src='administrator/product_images/$pro_image' width ='150px' height ='300px'>
        <figcaption style ='text-align : center;'>Item Name : $pro_title</figcaption>
        <figcaption style ='text-align : center;'>Description : $pro_detail</figcaption>
        <figcaption style ='text-align : center;'>Quantity : $pro_amount</figcaption>
        <a class='button' href='Booking/Booking.php'>Book Now</a>
        </figure>
        </div>
        ";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is highly vulnerable to SQL Injections. Never use unsanitized GET parameters directly in a query.

Comment: `<ul><a>` is not really valid HTML (thats probably the least of your issues though)  it should be `<ul><li><a ...></li></ul>` with list items.

Comment: `If I don't involved 'cat'`  I don't see how you are involving it, maybe there is an error there?  No way to know that.

Answer (score 0):

change `getCats()` function like below

```
function getCats(){

    global $con; 

    $get_cats = "select * from category";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

    $cat_row_array = array();

    while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $cat_row_array = $row_cats
    }

     foreach ($cat_row_array as $row_c){ 
        $cat_id = $row_c['category_id']; 
        $cat_title = $row_c['category'];
        echo "<ul><a href='Equipment.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></ul>";
    }

}
```